# canvas.removeChild(bitmapText) is not working

Tags: canvas, bitmap, html5-canvas, createjs

I am creating an animation and I want to remove a bitmap and replace it with a new one. I am able to add the new bitmap on the canvas but I cannot seem to remove the old one. My code looks like this:

```
var canvas;
var bitmapText;

// onload call
function init() {
    canvas = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
    bitmapText = bitmapTextInit(); // adds bitmap text to canvas
    counter = 0;
    canvas.update();
}

function bitmapTextInit() {
    var bitmapText = new createjs.Bitmap("bitmapText.png");
    canvas.addChild(balloonsText);
}

function removeBitmapText() {
    canvas.removeChild(bitmapText);
}

function addNewtext() {
    var newText = new createjs.Bitmap("newText.png");
}
```

I have a function that if == true it removes old image and adds new image as well as playing music.

```
function compareAndPlayInit() {
if (counter == 3) {
    console.log("true");
    removeBitMapText();
    addNewText();
    createjs.Sound.play(music);
}
```

When the counter reaches to 3, it adds the new bitmap text (addNewBitmapText();) and plays the music (createjs.Sound.play(music);) but does not remove the old bitmap text (removeBitMapText();).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `var` in `var bitmapText` (in `bitmapTextInit()`), you are creating a new variable.